# Convert multiple rows to single row for same Material

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple rows for each Material (number of rows will vary) with different values for Manufacturers  & Manufacturer part numbers. I need to convert this into one row for each Material with all the Manufacturers and Manufacturing part number in the same row.

Example provided below as I'm not able to attach images:

Existing Data

```
Material1 Mfgr1 MPN11    
          Mfgr2 MPN12

Material2 Mfgr2 MPN21    
          Mfgr3 MPN22    
          Mfgr4 MPN23
```

Required Data

```
Material1 Mfgr1 MPN11 Mfgr2 MPN12    
Material2 Mfgr2 MPN21 Mfgr3 MPN22 Mfgr4 MPN23
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Are the records already sequenced (materials, manufacturers, and part numbers in the order you want, all grouped into contiguous records), or does the task include locating the relevant records to consolidate the data?  Is each field currently in a separate column or all in a single cell per row?  Is the material listed just once as shown, or included in each record?  Do you want the result to have each field in a separate column or all in one cell per row, or each mfgr&MPN in a single cell?  What are the approximate quantities (total records, materials, max MPNs per material)?

Comment: @David, I'm currently doing this manually, and am not good at writing macros.

Comment: @ Fixer1234, yes all the records are sequenced as Material, Manufacturers, MPN with lot of other fields in between which I can remove. If the Material is same for first 3 rows, then the Material code will appear only once (in the first record). Also each field is in a separate column and the result too should be in separate column. Total records can run into a thousand rows with max. MPN/material as 5-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the trick:

```
Sub materialsinglerow()
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks, wks1 As Worksheet
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets(2)
continue = True
i = 1
j = 0
k = 2
emptycount = 0
lastmaterial = ""
While continue = True
    material = wks.Cells(i, 1)
    mfgr = wks.Cells(i, 2)
    mpn = wks.Cells(i, 3)
    If material <> "" Then
        j = j + 1
        k = 2
        wks1.Cells(j, 1) = material
        lastmaterial = material
    End If
    If mfgr <> "" Then
        wks1.Cells(j, k) = mfgr
        k = k + 1
        wks1.Cells(j, k) = mpn
        k = k + 1
    Else
        emptycount = emptycount + 1
    End If
    If emptycount > 10 Then
        continue = False
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

It reads the data from **Sheet1** and write the results to **Sheet2** assuming that the original data is in columns `A, B and C`.

It stops when there are more that 10 empty cells in column `C`.